# vim remove characters from buffer separations

Tags: vim, vimrc

If you look at the screencasts from [vimfiler](https://github.com/Shougo/vimfiler.vim) you can see that there's no characters in the separations, some are just a thin line. 
Where as mine as the default `|` pipe character.

My question is pretty simple, how do I customise my VIM so it looks more like it does in Vim filer and less like it does in default vim?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001337/vim-split-bar-styling),
To quote the original:

> You'll need to edit your colorscheme. The highlight group is
>   VertSplit.
>
> If you want to get rid of the pipe characters you can set ctermbg and
>   ctermfg to the same value.
>
> Additional information on styling vertical split borders*:
>
> *Taken from ib. answer below.
>
> In order to get rid of | characters, one should rather change vertical
>   separator using:
>
> ```
>     :set fillchars+=vert:\  (note the significant whitespace after the '\'
>     character)
> ```